# find the cumulative distribution function of a discrete density function $f(x)=2/3^x$

Tags: probability

From schaums probability and statistics:

find the cdf of the discrete probability density function of $f(x)=2/3^x$
where $x=1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$.

The answer in the back of this book is $1 - 3^{-y}$ where  $y \le x < y+1$, $y=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Not sure why the answer introduced the variable $y$, cant integrate a discrete function

My thoughts to compute the cdf up to an integer m would be

$$F(x)= \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2/3^x - \sum_{i=m}^\infty 2/3^x$$

$$F(x)= 1 - \sum_{i=m}^\infty 2/3^x$$

$$F(x)= 1 - 3^{1-m} \text{ for } m=1,2,3,\ldots$$

Comment: Write $F(x) = 1 - 3^{-\lfloor x\rfloor}$ for $x \ge 0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Is "3_x" intended to mean $3^x$.  In "internet speak" the underline, as in 3_x, is a **subscript**, 3^x would be the superscript or exponent.  Assuming you mean $f(x)= \frac{2}{3^x}$, It is easy to see that $F(1)= \frac{2}{3}$, $F(2)= \frac{2}{3}+ \frac{2}{9}= \frac{6+ 2}{9}= \frac{8}{9}$, $F(3)= \frac{2}{3}+ \frac{2}{9}+ \frac{2}{27}= \frac{18+ 6+ 2}{27}= \frac{26}{27}$.  You ought to be able to "guess" from that that $F(n)= \frac{3^n- 1}{3^n}$ and perhaps prove it by induction on n.

In general, the sum of a finite **geometric series", of the form $\sum_{i=0}^n ar^i$ is $\frac{a(1- r^{n+1})}{1- r}$.  Here a= 2 and r= 1/3 so that would be $\frac{2(1- 1/3^{n+1})}{1- 1/3}= 3(1- 1/3^{n+1}).  [b]Except[/b] that that sum starts at n= 0 while the series here starts at n= 1.  The n= 0 term would be $2(1/3)^0= 2$ so we need to subtract off 2: $F(n)= 3(1- 1/3^{n+1})- 2= 1- 1/3^n= \frac{3^n- 1}{3^n}$

Comment: yes it should be 3 to the power of x,  or 3^x

Comment: has 2 great answers, theoretically why is F(x) not equal to $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}$  - $\sum_{i=0}^{0}$ - $\sum_{i=m}^{\infty}$ if we are trying to calculate the probability up to integer m.